# What's the best way to have QTableView and Database in sync after inserting the record?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Let's suppose I have a QTableView with QSqlTableModel/Database. I don't want to let user edit the cells in QTableView. There are CRUD buttons that open new dialog forms and the user is supposed to enter data. After the user clicks dialog's OK button, what is the best way to insert that new record to database and view (to have them in sync), because database can be unavailable at the time (for example, inserting to remote database while having internet connection problems)?

My primary concern is I don't want to show phantom records in view and I want the user to be aware the record is not entered in the database.

I put some python code (but for Qt my problem is the same) to illustrate this, and have some other questions in comments:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtSql import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("names")
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Id")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Name")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.model.select()

        self.view = QTableView()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.view.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        #self.view.setColumnHidden(0, True)
        self.view.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.view.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.view.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        addButton = QPushButton("Add")
        editButton = QPushButton("Edit")
        deleteButton = QPushButton("Delete")
        exitButton = QPushButton("Exit")

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(addButton)
        hbox.addWidget(editButton)
        hbox.addWidget(deleteButton)
        hbox.addStretch()
        hbox.addWidget(exitButton)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.view)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        addButton.clicked.connect(self.addRecord)
        #editButton.clicked.connect(self.editRecord) # omitted for simplicity
        #deleteButton.clicked.connect(self.deleteRecord) # omitted for simplicity
        exitButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def addRecord(self):
        # just QInputDialog for simplicity
        value, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter the name:')
        if not ok:
            return

        # Now, what is the best way to insert the record?

        # 1st approach, first in database, then model.select()
        # it seems like the most natural way to me
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare("INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES(:name)")
        query.bindValue( ":name", value )
        if query.exec_():
            self.model.select() # now we know the record is inserted to db
            # the problem with this approach is that select() can be slow
            # somehow position the view to newly added record?!
        else:
            pass
            # message to user
            # if the record can't be inserted to database, 
            # there's no way I will show that record in view

        # 2nd approach, first in view (model cache), then in database
        # actually, I don't know how to do this
        # can somebody instruct me?
        # maybe:
        # record = ...
        # self.model.insertRecord(-1, record) #
        # submitAll()
        # what if database is unavailable?
        # what if submitAll() fails?
        # in that case, how to have view and model in sync?
        # is this the right approach?

        # 3. is there some other approach?

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName(":memory:")
db.open()
query = QSqlQuery()
query.exec_("DROP TABLE names")
query.exec_("CREATE TABLE names(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL, name TEXT)")
query.exec_("INSERT INTO names VALUES(1, 'George')")
query.exec_("INSERT INTO names VALUES(2, 'Rita')")
query.exec_("INSERT INTO names VALUES(3, 'Jane')")
query.exec_("INSERT INTO names VALUES(4, 'Steve')")
query.exec_("INSERT INTO names VALUES(5, 'Maria')")
query.exec_("INSERT INTO names VALUES(6, 'Bill')")
window = Window()
window.resize(600, 400)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Hi, I really don't understand how can you "show phantom records in view". Just consider that your model is your actual database. If you have some database problem such as connection or whatever, it's an other problem. Follow what RobbieE advise you and if you have a concrete problem, go back explaining correctly with examples what happened to you. KISS (Keep it simple, stupid).

Comment: with 2nd approach I can insert phantom records with ease. what if a user close the app in belief he entered the records, and the next loading of the app they are gone. besides, the model is not the database, they can be 'not in sync' any time.

Comment: Well, if the app is closed, it's quite hard to do what you want, is it really a problem for you ? There is absolutely no link with QTableView synchronization. User believing and what really do your program is just a GUI problem. If you worry about what the user believe (if the row is inserted or not), well open a confirmation dialog ? You are just shooting yourself in the foot with so complicated supposition.

Comment: again, thanks for your answer, but i just want to know which approach is better, first database, then model or first model then database.

Comment: the second approach (updating first model then database) is so strange, to me the first approach (first database, then model) is natural. only if database is updated I can be sure to sync the model (and view). and almost all Qt materials I saw, use the second approach. why?

Comment: If you have a model associated in a view in Qt, changing the model will automatically changing the view. Anyway, in your case, the most common way is refresh your database, refresh your model and refresh the view.

Comment: the problem is not between model and view, but between model and database

Comment: @ Martin "Anyway, in your case, the most common way is refresh your database, refresh your model and refresh the view". ok, thanks. is this approach somehow slower than second?

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `QSqlTableModel`. You can turn off all edit triggers in your table view and then pass the model to your data capturing forms and let the widgets bind to the model using `QDataWidgetMapper`, making sure the submit mode is set to manual so you can validate fields first.

Comment: so you suggest me the 2nd approach from my source comments? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: So you suggest me the 2nd approach from my source comments? I don't know how to do that. Is this the right order: 1. validating fields after enetering data to form, 2. inserting data to model, 3. submitAll(), 4. if it returns False, revertAll(), and user doesn't see new record? Q: Why should I/Qt change the model (even temporarily) if I don't know if the database will be updated? It's so strange.

Comment: whouldn't it be more natural to first try to insert that new record into the database and only when it succeeds, change the model (just insert that row in model)?

Answer (score 2):

RobbieE is right that I can use form editing (with QDataWidgetMapper) instead of direct cell editing, but my question was not about form or cell editing.

My question was which approach from my example is better, 1st or 2nd.

I changed the code and implemented the 2nd approach (which I don't like). Is it a good implementation?

But the question still remains. How do you (Py)Qt developers do CRUD with QtSql? First database, then model/view or first model/view, then database?

EDIT: I edited the example, added 3. approach (incomplete) and the possibility to simulate database closing. Now, it's easier to test all 3 approaches.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtSql import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("names")
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Id")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Name")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.model.select()

        self.view = QTableView()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.view.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        #self.view.setColumnHidden(0, True)
        self.view.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.view.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.view.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        addButton = QPushButton("Add")
        editButton = QPushButton("Edit")
        deleteButton = QPushButton("Delete")
        exitButton = QPushButton("Exit")
        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.combo.addItem("1) 1.Database, 2.Model (select)")
        self.combo.addItem("2) 1.Model, 2.Database")
        self.combo.addItem("3) 1.Database, 2.Model (insert)")
        self.combo.setCurrentIndex (0)
        self.checkbox = QCheckBox("Database Closed")

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(addButton)
        hbox.addWidget(editButton)
        hbox.addWidget(deleteButton)
        hbox.addWidget(self.combo)
        hbox.addWidget(self.checkbox)
        hbox.addStretch()
        hbox.addWidget(exitButton)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.view)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        addButton.clicked.connect(self.addRecord)
        #editButton.clicked.connect(self.editRecord) # omitted for simplicity
        #deleteButton.clicked.connect(self.deleteRecord) # omitted for simplicity
        self.checkbox.clicked.connect(self.checkBoxCloseDatabase)
        exitButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def checkBoxCloseDatabase(self):
        if self.checkbox.isChecked():
            closeDatabase()
        else:
            pass
            #db.open() # it doesn't work

    def addRecord(self):
        # just QInputDialog for simplicity
        value, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter the name:')
        if not ok:
            return

        # Now, what is the best way to insert the record?

        if self.combo.currentIndex() == 0:
            # 1st approach, first in database, then model.select()
            # it seems like the most natural way to me
            query = QSqlQuery()
            query.prepare("INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES(:name)")
            query.bindValue( ":name", value )
            if query.exec_():
                self.model.select() # now we know the record is inserted to db
                # the problem with this approach is that select() can be slow
                # somehow position the view to newly added record?!
            else:
                pass
                # message to user
                # if the record can't be inserted to database,
                # there's no way I will show that record in view
        elif self.combo.currentIndex() == 1:
            # 2nd approach, first in view (model cache), then in database
            QSqlDatabase.database().transaction()
            row = self.model.rowCount()
            self.model.insertRow(row)
            self.model.setData(self.model.index(row, 1), value)
            #self.model.submit()
            if self.model.submitAll():
                QSqlDatabase.database().commit()
                self.view.setCurrentIndex(self.model.index(row, 1))
            else:
                self.model.revertAll()
                QSqlDatabase.database().rollback()
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "Database not available. Please, try again later.")

        else:
            # 3rd approach, first in database, then model.insertRow()
            # it is not a complete solution and is not so practical
            query = QSqlQuery()
            query.prepare("INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES(:name)")
            query.bindValue( ":name", value )
            if query.exec_():
                #id = ... # somehow find id from the newly added record in db
                row = self.model.rowCount()
                self.model.insertRow(row)
                #self.model.setData(self.model.index(row, 0), id) # we don't know it
                self.model.setData(self.model.index(row, 1), value)
                # not a complete solution
            else:
                pass
                # do nothing, because model isn't changed
                # message to user

def closeDatabase():
    db.close()

def createFakeData():
    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_("DROP TABLE names")
    query.exec_("CREATE TABLE names(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL, name TEXT)")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO names VALUES(1, 'George')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO names VALUES(2, 'Rita')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO names VALUES(3, 'Jane')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO names VALUES(4, 'Steve')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO names VALUES(5, 'Maria')")
    query.exec_("INSERT INTO names VALUES(6, 'Bill')")
    #import random
    #for i in range(1000):
    #    name = chr(random.randint(65, 90))
    #    for j in range(random.randrange(3, 10)):
    #        name += chr(random.randint(97, 122))
    #
    #    query.prepare("INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES(:name)")
    #    query.bindValue( ":name", name )
    #    query.exec_()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
#db.setDatabaseName("test.db")
db.setDatabaseName(":memory:")
#openDatabase()
db.open()
createFakeData()
window = Window()
window.resize(800, 500)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

EDIT2 10/2019: I finally stopped using QSqlTableModel with RDBMSs. I use only QSqlQueryModel and don't need QSqlTableModel or QSqlRelationalTableModel. I don't use cell editing (like in Excel) and edit only whole records (rows) through forms. After clicking OK on form, I update the database and reselect QSqlQueryModel. Interestingly, after reselecting, the current row is again focused. QSql(Relational)TableModel has so much problems with handling database fields, they blew it completely, it's almost useless for serious work. They could have made it so much more useful than it is now.

My advice: for serious work and business apps, use QSqlQueryModel.

Comment: The question is what behavior you want to have? Do you want all fields to clear themselves when the database is not available? Then you can use the database as sole model. Otherwise you need another local copy of the data and have some kind of synchronization. I personally would use the database as sole source of data and built the model around it.

Comment: I want all fields to clear themselves (if I choose 2nd approach). But my question was what approach is better and more common, 1st or 2nd.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of your 2nd approach. Why would you like to insert the value first in the model and then in the database if the result is the same as for you 1st approach or e.g. when using`insertRecord`. Using the 1st one: you try to insert in the database if it fails the data won't be displayed. 2nd one: you display the data then try to insert and in case of fail you remove the data from the display again. So the 1st approach prevents you from unnecessary work. Of course you might want to take the responsibility for re-adding the data from the user but this is not straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in my comment your 1st approach is favorable over your 2nd one since it preventes you from doing unnecessary work. However if you are concerned about the amount of data which will be transfered by `QSqlTableModel.select` (what might make your application slow) you can use `QSqlTableModel.insertRecord` instead (see below my example for details). This tries to insert the record in the database and at the same time it will be registered in the model, even if the insert failed. So you would have to remove it manually again (in case of failure) by `QSqlTableModel.revertAll()`.

However you can use this fact that it is independently added to model to take the responsibility for re-adding data, for which the insert failed, from the user. That means the data get's inserted in the model and you try to submit it to the database later (the user has not to re-enter it). Here a small example (only the crucial parts):

(I used a two column table with columns INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT and VARCHAR(32))

```
record = QtSql.QSqlRecord()  # create a new record
record.append(QtSql.QSqlField('id', QtCore.QVariant.Int))  # add the columns
record.append(QtSql.QSqlField('value', QtCore.QVariant.String))
record.setValue('id', 0)  # set the values for every column
record.setValue('value', value)

if not self.model.insertRecord(-1, record):  # insert the record (-1 means at the end)
    self.queue = QueueRecord(self.model, self.table, self.model.rowCount()-1)  # in case of failure a new class is invoked which will manage the submission of this record (see below)
    # However, the record was added to the model and will therefore appear in the table
    self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('qstart()'), self.queue.insert)  # queue.insert is the method which handles submitting the record, the signal qstart() was created beforehand using QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    self.qstart.emit()  # start the submission handler
```

This is the class which handles the submission of the pending record:

```
class QueueRecord(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, model, table, row, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)

        self.model = model
        self.table = table
        self.delegate = table.itemDelegateForRow(row)  # get the item delegate for the pending row (to reset it later)
        self.row = row

        table.setItemDelegateForRow(row, PendingItemDelegate())  # set the item delegate of the pending row to new one (see below). In this case all cells will just display 'pending ...' so the user knows that this record isn't submitted yet.

        self.t1 = QtCore.QThread()  # we need a new thread so we won't block our main application
        self.moveToThread(self.t1)
        self.t1.start()

    def insert(self):
        while not self.model.submitAll():  # try to submit the record ...
            time.sleep(2)  # ... if it fails retry after 2 seconds.

        # record successfully submitted
        self.table.setItemDelegateForRow(self.row, self.delegate)  # reset the delegate
        self.t1.quit()  # exit the thread
```

Here's the delegate:

```
class PendingItemDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def displayText(self, value, locale):
        return 'pending ...'  # return 'pending ...' for every cell
```

So what this code basically does is it uses `insertRecord` to insert new data in the model / database. In case of failure the record will be anyway added to the model and we create a new class (which runs in a separate thread) to handle the re-submission of the data. This new class will change the display of pending row to indicate the user that this record has not been registered yet and try to submitt the data until it was successful. The delegate is reset and the thread left.

Like this you avoid calling `select()` but just insert one record in the table. Furthermore the user is no more responsible for providing the data again but this will be handled by a separate class.

**However** this is a really simple example and it should be **treated with caution**! For example the class `QueueRecord` uses the row number provided via `model.rowCount()-1` to refer to the pending element but if you delete elements in the meantime the row count will change and you will refer to the wrong element.

This example is for illustration purposes and can be used for further development but in its current state it's not meant to be used in actual applications.

You could for example change that there is a max. number of attempts for re-submission and after that 'pending ...' will change to 'failed' and a button for re-submission emerges, so the user just has to press this button to re-add the data after the connection to the database was established again.

By the way, to test this stuff I added a button to my mainwindow which closes / opens the database, so I started the application (opening automatically the database) then I closed it, inserted a value and openend it again.

Comment: interesting approach... but what if the user closes the app and go home (in belief he/she entered the record) before the record was added to database (in your thread)... tomorrow, there will be small surprise when he/she realizes there's no record

Comment: Well that's why the row is marked with `pending ...` so the user knows there's still a record which has not been submitted yet. The moment it was successfully submitted the row will display its actual content again. And you can also check in `Window.closeEvent` if there are still records pending and if so you can display a `QMessageBox.warning` to make the user aware that closing the application will lead to the loss of data.